# Replace single quote with backslash single quote in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to replace a single quote with back slash single quote.

I have been trying this but it results in a string with two backslashes and single quote or without any backslash and single quote.

```
re.sub("'","\'","Newton's method")
```

The above results in O/P : `Newton's method`

While `re.sub("'","\\'","Newton's method")` results in `Newton\\'s method`

I need `Newton\'s method` as the output.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update :**

This is a string which is created after parsing and is passed using an html form. Here `"Newton's method"` causes a problem since it deforms the json after the get request.

```
{'1': u'Newton metre', '0': u'Newton', '3': u'Newton (unit)', '2': u'Newton Centre, Massachusetts', '5': u'NewtonCotes formulas', '4': u'.30 Newton', '7': u'Newton Highlands, Massachusetts', '6': u"Newton's method", '9': u'List of things named after Isaac Newton', '8': u'Bill Newton'}
```

The html form gets this by a get request while the back end fetches it incorrectly.

```
 {'1': u'Newton metre', '0': u'Newton', '3': u'Newton (unit)', '2': u'Newton Centre, Massachusetts', '5': u'NewtonCotes formulas', '4': u'.30 Newton', '7': u'Newton Highlands, Massachusetts', '6': u
```

Comment: ``\\`` is just the representation of ``\``.

Comment: try this `print  re.sub("'","\\'","Newton's method")` `when you just do  re.sub("'","\\'","Newton's method")` it's `repr` is called

Comment: ``print re.sub("'", "\'","Newton's method")``. Your output is indeed with single backslash not two.

Comment: Both the single and the double backslashes return the json deformed error. I just thought it was a problem with the double slashes returned after replacing the single quote shown by the python interpreter.

Comment: How do you serialize to json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `\` or to use raw string literal:

```
>>> re.sub("'", "\\'","Newton's method")
"Newton\\'s method"
>>> re.sub("'", r"\'","Newton's method")
"Newton\\'s method"
```

BTW, for this case, you don't need to use regular expression. [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is enough:

```
>>> "Newton's method".replace(r"'", r"\'")
"Newton\\'s method"
```

---

**UPDATE**

`\\` is a way python `repr` represents backslash chracter in the string. If you print the string, you will see that it's a `\`.

```
>>> "Newton\\'s method"
"Newton\\'s method"
>>> print("Newton\\'s method")
Newton\'s method
```

Comment: @SiHa, `'\\'` is a single character string, not double `\ ` s.